# Weird limit with $e^x$

Tags: limits

> Here's a limit that is testing my strengths.
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} [(x^2+1)e^x]$$

**Personal work:**

$$\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} [(x^2+1)e^x] = \lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} (x^2e^x+e^x) = \lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} (x^2e^x)=L.$$

Let $x^2=u \iff x=-\sqrt u$, then $u_0=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}{x^2}=+\infty$

So, $$ L=\lim\limits_{u\to+\infty}{(u*e^{-\sqrt u})} =...$$

Although it looks correct for me, both Microsoft mathematics and symbolab show me the answer "$0$" so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that $x^2 = u \iff x = -\sqrt{u}$

Comment: Are you allowed to use l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: When you write $x^2=u$ you then have $2x=\ln u$, but that is not your problem.  The basic idea is that exponentials overpower polynomials, so that $e^x$ term goes to zero much faster than $x^2$ goes to infinity and the whole thing goes to zero.

Comment: The introduction of $\ln(u)$ seems wrong.  Perhaps you meant $2\ln(x)=\ln(u)$?

Comment: when we deal with limit $\to -\infty$ it is often convenient change variable in order to deal with a limit to $+\infty$ in order to avoid mistakes on sign

Comment: My mistake to use $\ln$ instead of root. Let me fix that and see what I get

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $y=-x\to \infty$, then

$$\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} [(x^2+1)e^x]=\lim\limits_{y\to \infty} [(y^2+1)e^{-y}]=\lim\limits_{y\to \infty} \frac{y^2+1}{e^{y}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Write your limit in the form $$\frac{x^2+1}{e^{-x}}$$ and the searched limit is zero

Answer (score 1):

A heuristic approach is to keep in mind that at $\pm\infty$ the exponential is stronger than any polynomial. This means that for any polynomial $p(x)$ we have the two limits

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}{e^x\over p(x)}=+\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}p(x)e^x=0$$

Our problem is in the second case. Let’s prove it. Can you convince yourself that if we prove

$$\forall m\geq 0 \lim_{x\to-\infty} x^me^x=0$$

we are done. (Yes indeed a polynomial is just a finite sum of monomials).

Let’s set $u=e^x$ this means $x=\ln{u}$ and $u\to 0$. Our limit rewrites

$$\lim_{u\to 0}mu\ln{u}=m\cdot \lim_{u\to 0}u\ln{u}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (x^2+1)e^x=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {x^2+1}{e^x}$$

Now by L'Hospital we have $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {x^2+1}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {2x}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {2}{e^x}=0$$

Comment: How did $-\infty $ turn into $+\infty$?

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis you must have noted that putting $y=-x$ and then changing the variable to x will give you required result

Comment: Well you didn't change the variable but $y=-x$ worked like a charm to me and the limit equalled to $0$, so, my problem was solved.